# Adding a prefix only to specific rows in dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `Fold_change` with a column named `Well` with 576 variables that are named `A1`, `A2`...and so on. 
I would like to add the prefix `Plate_1_` to the first 288 and the prefix `Plate_2_` to the rest of the variables.

I looked around and I found this possible solution

```
Fold_change$Well <- paste0('Plate_1_', Fold_change$Well)
```

But the problem here is that changes the name to all variables

So I tried to specify the number of rows:

```
Fold_change$Well[1:288] <- paste0('Plate_1_', Fold_change$Well[1:288])
```

but I receive this error

> Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 1:288, value = c(NA, NA, NA,
>   NA, NA, NA,  :   invalid factor level, NA generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Fold_change$Well <- as.character(Fold_change$Well) # change column class from factor to character first
Fold_change$Well[1:288] <- paste0('Plate_1_', Fold_change$Well[1:288])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the `Well` column to string first. Then perform manipulation and if needed convert it back to factor.

```
Fold_change$Well <- as.character(Fold_change$Well)
Fold_change$Well[1:288] <- paste0('Plate_1_', Fold_change$Well[1:288])
# anithing else
Fold_change$Well <- as.factor(Fold_change$Well)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution, just change the row number values:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  col_a = paste0("A", 1:10)
)
dat #fake data, just 10 rows
# col_a
# 1     A1
# 2     A2
# 3     A3
# 4     A4
# 5     A5
# 6     A6
# 7     A7
# 8     A8
# 9     A9
# 10    A10
```

We can use `paste0` to change values. And with `gsub` we can find the new pattern and update it just for the rows we want (5th to 10th in the example).

```
dat$col_a <- paste0("Plate_1_", dat$col_a) #changes names for all
dat$col_a[5:length(dat$col_a)] <- gsub("Plate_1_", "Plate_2_",dat$col_a[5:length(dat$col_a)]) 
#updates only for last 6 values
dat
# col_a
# 1  Plate_1_A1
# 2  Plate_1_A2
# 3  Plate_1_A3
# 4  Plate_1_A4
# 5  Plate_2_A1
# 6  Plate_2_A2
# 7  Plate_2_A3
# 8  Plate_2_A4
# 9  Plate_2_A5
# 10 Plate_2_A6
```